# Git Bash gives "Permission Denied" problem

Tags: python-3.x, git, github, git-bash, permission-denied

I wanted to try and install something from github the command is python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt i did this after git cloning im using Windows 10 and the "Run as admin" solution doesnt work can anyone please help me with this? It also still wont work after turning UAC off

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Permission+denied

Answer (score 2):

Avoid running commands as admin or turning UAC off. Instead use a [virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments) and installing packages relevant to this repository in its own isolated location.

Another option is to install to [the user site](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-to-the-user-site) using the `--user` option in your install command. This will install the packages to a non-admin location relevant to your user.